# CSV including column zero R

Tags: r, csv, dplyr, col

I have a `DataFrame` in R full of unique values from unique rownames that come from different files. Therefore, I have a column zero with the name of the file where the column name came from and a column 1 with unique rownames.

```
col0           col1
path/file1     name
path/file1     age
path/file2     color
path/file3     tree
path/file3     house
```

I want to export this as a CSV, but I haven't been able to write.csv including column0.

I have also tried mutating column 0 as a column, but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `write.table(file = "filename.csv", row.names = T)` ?

Comment: If @dc37's comment does not work for you, consider giving us something reproducible. For instance, sample unambiguous data (via `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) and the code you've tried. If there are warnings or errors, please include that verbatim. Thanks!